# Simple C# mortgage formula calculating wrong

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MortgageApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "", year, principle, month;
            double r, y, p;
            bool valid = false; 
            y = 0;
            r = 0;
            p = 0;



            while (valid == false)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the duration of the loan (Number of Years): ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (double.TryParse(input, out y))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(y);
                    valid = true;

                }
            }

            valid = false;
            while (valid == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the princple ammount: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (double.TryParse(input, out p))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p);
                    valid = true;
                }

            }


            valid = false;
            while (valid == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Interest Rate ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (double.TryParse(input, out r))
                {

                    valid = true;


                }

            }

            r = r / 100;

            Console.WriteLine(r);
            double top = p * r / 1200;
            Console.WriteLine(top);
            double x = (1 + (r / 1200.0));
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            double n = -12 * y;
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            double buttom = (1 - (Math.Pow(x, n)) );
            Console.WriteLine(buttom);
            double solution = top / buttom;

            Console.WriteLine(solution);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

This is suppose to be a simple mortgage app. I have the functionality but the formula is not correct.

Not sure if it's because I'm using doubles or if the problem is with my coding.

> (p r / 1200.0) / (1 - (1.0 + r / 1200.0) ^(-12.0 n)),
>
> Where
>
> - p = principal (dollars)
> - n = number of years
> - r = interest rate (percent)
> - m = monthly payment

Comment: what is your actual output vs. expected output??  with all of your `Console.WriteLine`s, does everything look correct, or are certain ones not calculating properly?]

Comment: Its not clear at all what you expect in this question.  Are you wanting someone to verify your math?  Perhaps [math.se] would be better.  Are you wanting someone to verify your code?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't think you should be dividing the rate by 100.  Either that or your equation should be dividing by 12 instead of 1200.

Comment: Also I'm not sure your formula is correct. I looked one up online which looks a little different and used it in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think the direct answer is that you're dividing the rate by 100, then dividing it again by 1200. You should either not divide by 100 to start with, or only divide by 12 later (I like the second option because it makes it clear you're talking about 12 months).

Another thing you might consider, in order to reduce repeated code, is to factor out a new function that gets a double from the user. Something like:

```
private static double GetDoubleFromUser(string prompt)
{
    double result;

    while (true)
    {
        if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (double.TryParse(input, out result)) break;
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, that is not a valid number. Please try again...");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, when you need a double, you just call this function and pass the prompt string. This makes your code much cleaner and easier to read. For example, your code could now be written as:

```
private static void Main()
{
    double years = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter the duration of the loan (in years): ");
    double principal = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter the princple ammount: ");
    double rate = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter the interest rate: ") / 100;

    Console.WriteLine("\nBased on these values entered:");
    Console.WriteLine(" - Number of years .... {0}", years);
    Console.WriteLine(" - Principal amount ... {0:c}", principal);
    Console.WriteLine(" - Interest rate ...... {0:p}", rate);

    double monthlyRate = rate / 12;
    double payments = 12 * years;

    double result =
        principal *
        (monthlyRate * Math.Pow(1 + monthlyRate, payments)) /
        (Math.Pow(1 + monthlyRate, payments) - 1);

    Console.WriteLine("\nYour monthly payment will be: {0:c}", result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```