# Error-handling when user inputs character instead of double

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, double

I made a simple application that calculates monthly payment for a loan based on principal number of years, and interest rate. If the user enters a character instead of a double the program crashes. How do I create a message saying "please input valid number" when someone inserts a letter?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HW1Udeshi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            bool Continue; 
            while (true) 
            {
                //initialize variables

                double r, yrs, m, p;
                string input, output;

                //principle amount
                Console.Write("Enter a Principle Amount: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                //Int32.Parse
                p = double.Parse(input);

                //Number of years 
                Console.Write("Enter Number of Years: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                //Int32.Parse
                yrs = double.Parse(input);

                //Interest Rate
                Console.Write("Enter Interest rate: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                //Int32.Parse
                r = double.Parse(input);

                //monthly payment  formula:
                m = (p * r / 1200.0) / (1 - Math.Pow((1.0 + r / 1200.0),(-12 * yrs)));

                //Round two decimal pts 
                m = Math.Round(m,2);

                //output
                output = m.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Monthly payment is " + m + ".");
                Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Continue y/n?");
                if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
                {
                    Continue = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

            } 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up about Double.TryParse.

Also: Principal*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `TryParse` instead of int.parse  something like this

```
           Console.Write("Enter a Principle Amount: ");
           input = Console.ReadLine();
           double.TryParse(input,out p);
           if(p== 0)
           {
             Console.Write("please input valid number");
           }
```

Comment: This seemed to work the easiest way thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I usually write a separate method for it, using `double.TryParse` because it returns true if the conversion was successful and assigns the converted value to the out parameter. In the following example, if `TryParse` succeeds, I break out of the `while (true)` loop and return the result. Otherwise, I tell the user to try again:

```
private static double GetDoubleFromUser(string prompt)
{
    double result;

    while (true)
    {
        if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (double.TryParse(input, out result)) break;
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, that is not a valid number. Please try again...");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then, in your main code, you don't have to worry about input and output or validation, you can just do something like:

```
double principal = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter a Principal Amount: ");
double years = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter Number of Years: ");
double rate = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter Interest rate: ");
```

Comment: For a more complete example, check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567033/simple-c-sharp-mortgage-formula-calculating-wrong/29567765#29567765